# How to get text from specific href with jsoup?

Tags: java, android

I get text from http://m.wol.jw.org/en/wol/dt/r1/lp-e/2014/6/26 via jsoup in my android app.
It looks like:

```
public static void refreshFromNetwork(Context context) {
    Document document;
    Elements dateElement;
    Elements textElement;
    Elements commentElement;
    try {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        sDayURL = sURL + "/" + year + "/" + month + "/" + day;

        document = Jsoup.connect(sDayURL).get();
        if (document.hasText()) {
            dateElement = document.select(".ss");
            textElement = document.select(".sa");
            commentElement = document.select(".sb");

            sDate = dateElement.text();
            sText = textElement.text();
            sComment = commentElement.html();
            sSavedForCheckingDate = sLocalDate;
            savePrefs(context);
            sDayURL = null;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext,
                    mContext.getString(R.string.warning_unstable_connection),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But there are some hrefs in text. When the cursor is on them, pops up with text frame.
I can't post images, so see it there: http://habrastorage.org/files/45e/b09/17f/45eb0917f3644bbd9e5ea2b79d98363d.png

But when I try to get text from that href (I get it from sComment with html), it returns me all the text (which displays when I click on href), not part of it, like in popup. I'm not a web developer, so I don't understand, how to get only the desired text. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the snapshot below to get only the text on pop-up

[Click the pop-up href](https://imageshack.com/i/npnuqup)

[See the text the popup text is on the this page also, to extract only the text shown on popup simply use this class and display the contents](https://imageshack.com/i/n66ns8p)

When you click on the link href, a new page open with the same text with red font this is the text you need as it is the pop-up text, now you have just use

```
String Href=Scomment.attr("href");
Document doc=Jsoup.connect(Href).get();
Element element= doc.getElementById("p101");
String dialogtext=element.text();
```

This is the solution to you question.
Hope it'll help you

Comment: Thanks, but I see every werb has this class. So, when I write
    Document document;
        Elements elements;
        try {
            sDayURL = "http://m.wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1102014007/91/0";

            document = Jsoup.connect(sDayURL).get();
            if (document.hasText()) {
                elements = document.select(".sz");
                System.out.println(elements.text());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

It get me all the text

Comment: There are not method getElementByClass, only getElementsByClass. 
String Href = "http://m.wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1102014007/91/0";
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(Href).get();
            Elements element = doc.getElementsByClass("sz");
            String dialogtext = element.text();
            System.out.println(dialogtext);

And it returns all the text, too

Comment: use getElementById("p101"); it will return only the text having id "p101"

Comment: Ohh... But how do I know what id will be going in the other case?

Comment: you can find it on the page by inpect element, see the image I sent to you in my answer. you can find there <div id="p101"> use the id of what text you want to fetch.

Comment: Ouh, I foind it in result href. http://m.wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwt/E/2013/20/4#h=101:0-102:0 See the penultimate digit. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you JW? Sorry, I haven't enough reputation for chat.

Comment: Write me on bringoff@ukr.net , if you want

Answer (score 0):

Use `sComment = commentElement.text();` instead.

Comment: I need the text which popups, not the link title

Comment: String relHref = commentElement.attr("href"); using this attr method you have to first get the url of the link and then this relHref again pass through the Jsoup.connect(relHref).get() and extract what you want from this. Hope it'll help you

Comment: Mmm... I did exactly that, but it returns all of the text, not the one in the pop-up window

Comment: All the text including the one which is displayed on the popup?

Comment: Look, when I click on href, the whole chapter displays. When I when I give this link for jsoup it get all the chapter, too. I need the part of chapter, which displays in popup.

Comment: You have to find the pop-up dialog class or id, if you inspect and find them you can just parse only the pop-up text into you app. Just find the dialog in html of the page.

Comment: It looks like I can't found it

Comment: The pop-up opens using javascript, but actual design and text is on the index.html file, in order to fetch text from pop-up you have to find the dialog, can you please post snapshot of html so I check it out

Comment: brother when you click on href, it display all the text including on which is on the popup, so you have inspect the new open page and extract the only text from there, you just print out the whole href text that is why you get all the text.

Comment: But how can I find only needful part of text?